# Можно ли IEnumerator<T> привести к IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#

Объясните,пожалуйста,почему в ниже приведенном коде возможен *Upcast* типа *IEnumerator<int>* к типу *IEnumerable<int>*,ведь *IEnumerator<T>* не наследуется от *IEnumerable<T>*

---

```
static IEnumerator<int> GetOddNumbers(params int[] numbers)
{
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        if (number % 2 != 0) yield return number;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    IEnumerable<int> enumerable = (IEnumerable<int>)GetOddNumbers(1, 2, 3);
    IEnumerator<int> enumerator = GetOddNumbers(1, 2, 3);



    //List<int> oddnumbers = new List<int>(GetOddNumbers(1, 2, 3));

    //foreach (var number in oddnumbers)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine(number);
    //}

    //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Извините, неверно прочитал вопрос вначале, ответ полностью переписан.

---

Дело в том, что в C# любой объект можно закастить к любому интерфейсу на этапе компиляции:

```
interface I1 { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        I1 i1 = (I1)(new Program());
    }
}
```

В рантайме, если объект реально не имплементирует интерфейс, выбросится исключение `InvalidCastExcetion`.

---

Почему же разрешён каст к интерфейсу, хотя объект на самом деле не имплементирует этот интерфейс? Рассмотрим код

```
Program p = new Program();
I1 i1 = (I1)p;
```

В этой точке статический тип выражения `p`, на которое навешен каст — `Program`. Но реальный, динамический тип может быть любой, производный от `Program`. И этот тип вполне может имплементировать интерфейс! Поэтому компилятор не может *доказать*, что каст невозможен, и откладывает проверку до момента реального выполнения.

Сравните:

```
interface I1 { }

sealed class Program // добавили sealed
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        I1 i1 = (I1)(new Program()); // Не компилируется, ошибка CS0030
    }
}
```

В этих условиях компилятор таки может доказать, что выражение не может имплементировать интерфейс, ведь класс `Program` этот интерфейс не имплементирует, а производных классов быть не может. Вот этот код и не компилируется.

---

Компилятор, конечно, мог бы быть суперумным, и увидеть, что выражение `GetOddNumbers(...)` есть вызов функции-генератора, и не имплементирует `IEnumerable<int>`. Но при этом он должен был бы решать это не по декларируемому типу (`IEnumerator<int>`), а анализируя поток выполнения программы. Это в общем случае неразрешимая задача, так что компилятор C# и не пробует браться за неё. (За исключением нескольких простых случаев, да.)

Comment: а разве можно с кастить к интерфейсу наследника имплементирующего его сохраненного в переменной базового класса?

Comment: @Grundy: Не сумел распарсить вашу фразу :)

Comment: [Вот :-)](http://paste.org.ru/?gqnxer) - действительно работает :)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да, куда оно денется?

Comment: @VladD спасибо! Можно еще вопрос? :)
Почему в методе GetOddNumbers возвращающим значением может быть и IEnumerable<T> и IEnumerator<T>?Я проверял 2 варианта, и в ходе работы программы не возникало каких-либо ошибок )

Comment: @Vladmes: Так описано [в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) и предписано стандартом языка :-\ У этого метода в зависимости от возвращаемого типа (IEnumerable или IEnumerator) генерируется немного разный код.

Comment: @Vladmes: Вариант, описанный в вашем вопросе, должен выдавать исключение при выполнении. У меня по крайней мере выдаёт, а у вас?

Comment: @VladD Спасибо,буду в этом разбираться :)